# What's walkway contour?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-meaning

> "Accessibility is most often used to describe facilities or amenities to assist people with disabilities, as in 'wheelchair accessible'. This can extend to Braille signage, wheelchair ramps, audio signals at pedestrian crossings, **walkway contours**, website design, and so on."
>
> From [Accessibility | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the shape (contour) that a path follows in three dimensions. This includes any turns that the path might make as well as the slope of the path.

Contour [definition](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contour) 2:

> the general form or structure of something

[Here are some images](https://www.google.com/search?q=walkway%20contour&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=wsr3VJegIM2ayATr4oKACw&ved=0CB4QsAQ&biw=1111&bih=799).

As to the document, the implication is that in order for a walkway to be wheelchair accessible, the walkway must be wide enough to allow for a wheelchair and avoid sharp turns.  It must also be flat enough that it is easy for someone in a wheelchair or pushing a wheelchair to remain in control and follow slopes rather than including stairs.

Comment: The explanation is fine, thanks. But I don't think the document implies the walkway to be wheelchair accessible, it just means the walkway needs to be accessible in general :)

Comment: In ADA terms, "accessible" in terms of walkways can be synonymous with "wheelchair accessible". That's what the first sentence is saying.

Comment: +1 for going beyond the dictionary definition and explaining that in this context, "contour" suggests the path's shape in three dimensions. And the pictures explain the specific kind of curviness suggested by "contour" better than anything!